# Microsoft Access - Integrity through relationships

Tags: database, ms-access

I had a question about relationships in Access 2010. I have 2 tables:

```
Table 1       Table 2

ID Name       ID Name
1  George     1
2  Linda      2
3  Frank      3
```

Where I purposely left name in table 2 blank because I want to enforce a relationship between name in table 1 and name in table 2 with referential integrity.  Currently if I enter a name into table 2 that is not in table 1 it does not catch it as an error. I want there to be data validation and I thought relationships was the way to do that.  Am I understanding referential integrity wrong?

Comment: Yup, you got is wrong. You should not store the same data in multiple tables anyway, just a reference (foreign key) to the main table (primary key). [What is referential integrity](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/1233/referential-integrity-ri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce consistency via [Data Macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?CorrelationId=c5194303-d66f-41d6-82e9-fcc78a3d6caa&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010378170), introduced since 2010. You need the following:

- a data macro that `RaiseError` when an item is inserted/updated in `table2` which does not have a match in `table1`
- a data macro that handles `table2` references when a given record from table1 is removed

However, this seems unintuitive. You could have a foreign key in `table2` referring `table1`'s id.